# On Macbook, my permalinks with post name don't work. Returning 404 error

Tags: permalinks

I can see my pages when I set "plain" it works fine, page opens fine. But, when I try to use "post name" as the permalink, it returns 404 error. This is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I can access the home page (frontend) and the admin, just fine. What else can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you be more specific. Is this a local server? Are you using any caching, reverse proxy on your website. Are you trying to access a custom post type url or is this affecting all URLs?

Comment: To be very specific, yes , this is a local server. I created a page, and in Permalinks Settings this option (post name).

Comment: oh ok, what are you using as a web server ? If it's apache, make sure you have mod_rewrite module enabled

Comment: it's enabled through .htaccess.

Comment: well adding `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` to your `.htaccess` file wont enable the module. It will enable the rewriting **if** the module is enabled! make sure it is enabled within your config file along with libphp5

Comment: What is your local url and are you using that in wp-admin/Settings/General?